# Background traffic managment in android

Tags: android, server, sftp, jsch

I'm developing an android App that collect some data from 4 sensors via Bluetooh and at the end send the data to a SFTP server.
I'm using the JSCh (ChannelSftp), the thing works fine with some servers, but with the server of my University the App crash.
I have performed a deep debug with the IT officer and we discovered that once the SSH channel is open some background traffic arrives to the server (ex.: myIP --- otherIP--- packet). At that point the firewall close the connection and the App crash.

Is there a way to block the background traffic for a small window of time from the App?. Has anyone had the same problem as me?

Thanks in advance

```
public class SftpClass extends AsyncTask <Object, Void, String> {


    private Context context;
    private long size;
    private long fileSize;

    public SftpClass (Context con){
        context = con;
        size = 0;
        fileSize = -1;
    }


    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Object... params){
        //Params: File file, String host, String port, String username, String password
        File file = (File) params[0];
        String host = (String) params[1];
        String port = (String) params[2];
        String username = (String) params[3];
        String password = (String) params[4];
        String path = (String) params[5];

        int portnumber = Integer.valueOf(port);

        fileSize = file.length();
        String localFilePath = file.getAbsolutePath();
        String fileName = localFilePath.substring(localFilePath.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
        String remoteFilePath =  fileName;  

        JSch jsch = new JSch();
        Session session = null;
        try {
            session = jsch.getSession(username, host, portnumber);
            session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
            session.setPassword(password);
            session.connect();

            Channel channel = session.openChannel("sftp");

            channel.connect();
            final ChannelSftp sftpChannel = (ChannelSftp) channel;
            sftpChannel.put(localFilePath, path+remoteFilePath);

            try
            {
                Thread.sleep(3000);
            }
            catch(InterruptedException ex)
            {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }

            SftpATTRS attrs = null;
            try {
                attrs = sftpChannel.lstat(path+remoteFilePath);
            } catch (SftpException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if ( attrs != null){
                size = attrs.getSize();
            }

            sftpChannel.exit();
            session.disconnect();
        } catch (JSchException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SftpException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
        return "";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        if (size == fileSize){
            Toast.makeText(context, "File uploaded\n"+Long.toString(size)+"Bytes", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: app side would not relevant, this should be resolved at server side by disable firewal.

Comment: What is *"some background traffic"*?? -- Are you aware that SSH is a complex protocol that does lot of data exchange, when the connection is opening -- and that it is perfectly normal?

Comment: Unfortunately, University firewalls can't be touched. The set up has been certified and variations are not allowed.
With "some background traffic" I mean the one addressed to Google, Yahoo and other phone apps. That traffic is incorrectly sent to the server, the firewalls seeing strange things close the communication.